# JavasScript: Why does my_array.length not work?

Tags: javascript

Version 1:

```
var spamfoo = new Array();
spamfoo.push(['name', 'url']);
spamfoo.push(['dog', 'cat']);
alert(spamfoo);
// Alerts: name,url,dog,cat
alert(spamfoo.length);
// Alerts: 2
// ??? (shouldn't this be 4?)
```

Version 2:

```
var spamfoo = new Array();
spamfoo.push(['name', 'url']);
spamfoo = spamfoo + ['dog', 'cat'];
alert(spamfoo);
// Alerts: name,url,dog,cat
alert(spamfoo.length);
// Alerts: 15
// ??? (this one I wasn't sure about anyways because I didn't know if you could add an array)
```

How is this possible? Doesn't `['value', 'value']` make an array and doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that `my_array.length` does work but you're missing some of the implicit type conversions that are happening and what `push()` does.

In the first example, you are creating a multidimensional array. Technically it's an array of arrays rather than a true multidimensional array. The first code snippet creates this array of arrays:

```
[
  ["name", "url"],
  ["dog", "cat"]
]
```

which is of length 2 so that result is correct.

The second example's use of the concatenation operator `+` converts `spamfoo` to a string, which means that `length` is now returning the string length. The string length is 15 so this too is correct.

You might want to add this line to your examples:

```
alert(typeof spamfoo);
```

If so you'll see the first example displays `object` and the second displays `string`.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, you'll get a nested array (2x2), hence `spamfoo.length` returns 2. It looks like:

```
[
    ['name', 'url'],
    ['dog', 'cat']
]
```

The second part, is as [cletus said above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226084/javasscript-why-does-my-array-length-not-work/2226107#2226107), is a type casting into string

Comment: +1. Agree. After pushing twice, the container will contain 2 things. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Yes I agree. Basically your inserting another array object into your array.

Answer (score 1):

You want to flatten those arrays before pushing them. Try this:

```
var spamfoo = [];
Array.prototype.push.apply(spamfoo, ["name", "url"]);
Array.prototype.push.apply(spamfoo, ["dog", "cat"]);
alert(spamfoo.length); // alerts 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

var spamfoo = new Array();
var x=["name", "url","d"];
spamfoo.push("name", "url","d");
spamfoo.push("xxxx");
//spamfoo.push('dog');

// Alerts: name,url,dog,cat
alert(spamfoo.length);

Answer (score 0):

The first one I posted is wrong. There is the extra "var x=xxxxxxxxx"

This is the correct one.

```
var spamfoo = new Array();

spamfoo.push("name", "url","d");
spamfoo.push("xxxx");
//spamfoo.push('dog');

// Alerts: name,url,dog,cat
alert(spamfoo.length);
```

K prime is right.. This is a mistake spamfoo.push(['name', 'url']);
spamfoo.push(['dog', 'cat']);

Your inserting an array into an array object.